# SQL - Creating associations between fields (Transitive relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join, group-by

I have a sql table that contains a list of affiliations where Entity A owns Entity B, Entity B owns Entity C, etc...  I don't have any sql text to include here because I'm not sure fundamentally where to start.  I believe that joining the table to itself multiple times will not give the desired results because it would exclude certain 'affiliations'.

What I would like to do is group them with some value for those entities that are affiliated to each other (I am agnostic as to what value is used for the grouping).  This is probably best explained with the following example.

Simplifying my problem, I have the following two columns in my table. (The number at the beginning is informational and just represents the record number in order to help with my description below.)

```
1 A | B
2 Z | B
3 Y | B
4 B | C
5 B | D
6 D | E
7 F | G
```

So, A & B are considered "affiliated".  This also means that because "B" shows up in records #2,3,4 and 5, that Z, Y, C, and D are also affiliated with A & B, thus:

> A, B, C, D, Y, and Z are all affiliated.

I also want to go one step further, and see that (RE: #5) since B & D are affiliated, that (RE:#6) B and E should also be affiliated.  Thus the full affiliation list would look something like:

> A, B, C, D, **E**, Y, and Z

Since F & G only show up in their affiliation to each other, they would not be part of the larger affiliation I just described.  Therefore, I would want my expected results to be something like:

```
Entity | Grouping
A | Group1
B | Group1
C | Group1
D | Group1
E | Group1
Y | Group1
Z | Group1
F | Group2
G | Group2
```

I have done my best to explain this, so my apologies in advance for any omission of details or confusing/incomplete explanations.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!
Best,
Robby

Comment: It looks like you want a transitive affiliation relationship. That is, `A | B` means that `A` is affiliated with `B` and `B` is affiliated with `A`. Is that correct? This is relevant because Oracle has a `START WITH ... CONNECT BY PRIOR ... ` feature for doing hierarchical queries. Similarly SQL Server can handle recursion in so-called common table experssions. Neither feature assumes transitivity, so that will have to be added.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is transitive, A|B is equal to B|A. How would you 'add' the transitivity you referred to?

Comment: Let me also add, as a general comment (and I realize this may be asking too much because of the complexity), I would like to try and find an approach that only uses the more basic joins as I must eventually convert the sql approach into a more restrictive piece of software. I have the flexibility to break it into as many "steps" as needed once a general approach is established.

Answer (score 0):

Well i cant say anything for ORACLE, but you could manage it with recursive CTE in sql server. Heres my sample solution, it does what you asked for assuming that you have a table witch maps relation many-to-many from one table to itself

```
DECLARE @testData table (EntityID int, EntityName varchar(1))
DECLARE @EntityRelations table (EntityID1 int, EntityID2 int)

INSERT INTO @testData
SELECT 1, 'A'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'B'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'C'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'D'
UNION
SELECT 5, 'E'
UNION
SELECT 6, 'F'
UNION
SELECT 7, 'G'
UNION
SELECT 8, 'Y'
UNION
SELECT 9, 'Z'

INSERT INTO @EntityRelations
SELECT 1, 2
UNION
SELECT 9, 2
UNION
SELECT 8, 2
UNION
SELECT 2, 3
UNION
SELECT 2, 4
UNION
SELECT 4, 5
UNION
SELECT 6, 7;


WITH Affiliations (EntityID, Entity1Name, Entity2Name) AS
(
    SELECT r.EntityID1
          ,e.EntityName as Entity1Name
          ,e2.EntityName as Entity2Name
    FROM @EntityRelations r
        JOIN @testData e ON e.EntityID = r.EntityID1
        JOIN @testData e2 ON e2.EntityID = r.EntityID2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.EntityID1
          ,e.EntityName as Entity1Name
          ,e2.EntityName as Entity2Name
    FROM @EntityRelations r
        JOIN @testData e ON e.EntityID = r.EntityID1
        JOIN @testData e2 ON e2.EntityID = r.EntityID2
        JOIN Affiliations a ON a.EntityID = r.EntityID2
)

,AffiliationsReverse (EntityID, Entity1Name, Entity2Name) AS
(
    SELECT r.EntityID2
          ,e.EntityName as Entity1Name
          ,e2.EntityName as Entity2Name
    FROM @EntityRelations r
        JOIN @testData e ON e.EntityID = r.EntityID1
        JOIN @testData e2 ON e2.EntityID = r.EntityID2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.EntityID2
          ,e.EntityName as Entity1Name
          ,e2.EntityName as Entity2Name
    FROM @EntityRelations r
        JOIN @testData e ON e.EntityID = r.EntityID1
        JOIN @testData e2 ON e2.EntityID = r.EntityID2
        JOIN AffiliationsReverse a ON a.EntityID = r.EntityID1
)


SELECT DISTINCT EntityName
FROM
(
SELECT a.Entity1Name AS EntityName
FROM Affiliations a
    JOIN AffiliationsReverse ar ON ar.EntityID = a.EntityID

UNION

SELECT a.Entity2Name AS EntityName
FROM Affiliations a
    JOIN AffiliationsReverse ar ON ar.EntityID = a.EntityID

UNION

SELECT ar.Entity1Name AS EntityName
FROM Affiliations a
    JOIN AffiliationsReverse ar ON ar.EntityID = a.EntityID

UNION

SELECT ar.Entity2Name AS EntityName
FROM Affiliations a
    JOIN AffiliationsReverse ar ON ar.EntityID = a.EntityID


) s
```