# How to group all linked objects in a undirected cyclic graph

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has customers and its joint customers. e.g Customer 1 has a joint customer 2. Customer 1 is also a joint customer to Customer 3.

I am trying to group all customers that are linked and assign same `GroupCustNo` to them. In below table 1-2 are linked, 3-1 are linked. So 2-3 are also linked. All customers from 1 to 8 in below table are thus linked to each other and will have same `GroupCustNo`.

**tbl_GroupCustomers**:

```
CustNo   JtCustNo  GroupCustNo    
---      -------     ------   
1           2          null
2           null       null
3           1          null
4           1          null
4           5          null
5           6          null
5           7          null
6           null       null
7           null       null
8           5          null
```

The recursive stored procedure I wrote is below. I am calling this in a while loop for each CustNo:

```
exec usp_UpdateGroupCustomerNo 1, 1
```

The stored procedure ran successfully for most of the customers but threw up

> Recursion Limit of 32 reached

error for some customers. These are customers that have many joint customers and are also Joint Customers to other customers.

It seems recursion wont work here and I am at a loss on how to proceed. Please let me know if there are any alternate methods to address this problem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateGroupCustomerNo]
    @MainCustNo int, @GrpNo int
AS 
    declare @JtCustNo int; declare @MainCustNo2 int;

    if exists(select 1 from tbl_GroupCustomer 
              where CustNo = @MainCustNo and groupcustomernumber is null)
    begin    
        update tbl_GroupCustomer 
        set groupcustomernumber = @grpno 
        where CustNo = @MainCustNo 
          and groupcustomernumber is null

        DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR  
             select JtCustNo 
             from tbl_GroupCustomer 
             where CustNo = @MainCustNo and JtCustNo is not null

        OPEN db_cursor   

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @JtCustNo   

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
        BEGIN   
            select @JtCustNo as JtCustNo      

            exec usp_UpdateGroupCustomerNo @JtCustNo, @GrpNo

            DECLARE db_cursor2 CURSOR LOCAL FOR  
                select CustNo 
                from tbl_GroupCustomer 
                where JtCustNo = @JtCustNo 
                  and groupcustomernumber is null

            OPEN db_cursor2

            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor2 INTO @MainCustNo2   

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
            BEGIN   
                if exists(select 1 from tbl_GroupCustomer 
                          where CustNo = @MainCustNo2 
                            and groupcustomernumber is null)
                begin     
                    exec usp_UpdateGroupCustomerNo @MainCustNo2, @GrpNo
                end

                FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @MainCustNo2   
            END   

            CLOSE db_cursor2   
            DEALLOCATE db_cursor2

            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @JtCustNo   
    END  

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
END
```

Comment: You are calling the stored procedure recursively.  Hence, you are calling it too many times.

Comment: @Gordon I know but how do I get the desired result in that case. Any different approach I can take?

Comment: A dirty hack would be to pass recursion level to the SP and exit w/o action if limit is reached, then run your SP as many times, as it takes to update all data. But I would look for a way to do that in a query instead of SP.

Comment: @ajeh Yes recursive CTE is what I think will work. BTW my requirement is the same as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764028/sql-creating-associations-between-fields-transitive-relationship