# sql generate group on related groups

Tags: sql, grouping

Sorry, if question unclear, i had misstakes it first tables. I made some updates:

Database: PostgreSQL

[image]

I want to group table based on transition (if a=b & b=c then a=c)

[image]

Adding a pair (4,c) will merge 2 groups to one "group1".

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the expected output?

Comment: Based on what condition you want this result?

Comment: In the first table relation between 4 and 2 not obvious (not direct). In the output i will get a direct relation between elements.

Comment: "4" and "2" related through the "1". I want "4" and "2" related directly, based on "1" relation.

Comment: @Malenkymuk . . . This requires support for hierarchical or recursive queries -- syntax that differs based on the database you are using.  Please tag with your database.

Comment: Hi, Hope this is what you are expecting.select id, groups, nvl(grou, 'group2')   from 
(select distinct s1.id as id, s1.groups as groups, s2.a as grou from Scenario3 s1
left outer join 
(select id, groups, 'group1' as a from Scenario3 where id = 1) s2
on (s1.groups = s2.groups) order by s1.id);

Answer (score 0):

i assume u want a.b.c to be group1  and the d as group2..
the groupby will work perfectly fine with aliases..

but the number of group op wants  is 3 millions groups so a stored proc with a incremental in the end and group by will work fine..

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment. Also, if he group by won't work here as it will show 5 for d as answer.

Comment: you need to  have it alias for group2 instead of 5 for d

Comment: No. It can't be done with a simple Group by. For how many groups you will give alias?

Comment: About 3 million groups.

Comment: yes so a stored proc with a incremental number in  the end ,

Comment: that is a reasonable approach

Comment: In first table 1 2 3 4 are related, but no directly. It will complicate to find relation for 5 and 4 for example.  Second table helps to find relation faster.

Comment: so you need to put that logic in when you create a stored proc..

Comment: Are you sure of stored proc? Something tells me that this is a simple problem about mathematical subsets

Comment: well, pls explain what logic you wan to implement then something can be worked out.. but either way this will not be a simple query

Comment: I guess its transitive problem. If A = B AND B = C THEN A = C.

Comment: Posible here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764028/sql-creating-associations-between-fields-transitive-relationship

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it looks like you want to find out transitive relationship.
You can do that with following query. But if the goal here is just to identify the relationship among different groups with their respective id, i guess you can afford to have groups which are not getting incremented with 1.

According to your given example in OP, i think it won't affect you if end result has `group1` and `group5` instead of `group2`.

If mention result is fine then you can do that with following updated query. Giving group names in successive manner will impact on query performance which you don't want as you've 3 million of groups.

Please try following query:

```
select t1.id,   concat('group', min(t2.minId)) groups                                                                          
from t1
join
   (select min(id) minId, groups
    from t1
    group by groups
    ) t2
    on t1.groups = t2.groups
    join (select @cnt := 1)y
  group by t1.id;
```

Demo : [Click here](https://rextester.com/FNU54030)

Comment: Adding  (5,a) row gets group3. It is not correct. (5,a) must be at group1.

Comment: if we add (5,a) then shall it display both (5, group1) as well as (5, group2) ?

Comment: This case group2 is not actual because (5,d) come to group1 through the (5,a). So this case we will remove group2

Comment: i've updated the query accordingly. Kindly go through answer once again.

Comment: Is it working as expected?